# Android MediaPlayer :: Issues

Tags: java, android

I know this is a very common question. However, I am having trouble to play the sound in my application by using **MediaPlayer** class despite my logic is correct. Currently, I have a shake detection features in my application. Every time the device is shaken, it should play a sound. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
private SoundManager mSoundManager;
private TextView xText;
private Context context;
private AudioPool ap;
int id1,id2;
File directory;

MediaPlayer player, mPlayer;
AudioCollective ac;
Lagu la;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xText);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();

   la = new Lagu();
    la.initLagu(MainActivity.this);

    mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShake(int count) {

            la.playLagu();
            xText.setText("Shake:"+count);

        }
    });
}

public class Lagu {
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
public Lagu(){
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
public void initLagu(Context theContext){
    mPlayer.create(theContext, R.raw.na);
}
public void playLagu(){
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The problem is the application ***DOES NOT*** play the sound every time the phone is shaken. Not even one time the application will play the sound. FYI, the format of the song is MP3. Someone here please tell me what is going wrong with my application? Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check the log for warnings or error, sometimes these classes can behave differently from device to device.

Comment: Hi, there is no errors or warnings shows in the log. It means the logic is correct.But I still dont know why it doesnt play the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) for `Mediaplayer.create()`:

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

Note: the method `Mediaplayer.create()` is a static method which returns a ready-to-use `Mediaplayer`.

So you need to assign the return value to your *mPlayer*
You don't need any `OnPreparedListener` - simply call `start()`

```
public class Lagu {

MediaPlayer mPlayer;

public Lagu(){
    // do nothing or call initLagu() here
    // in this case skip the method call from the Activity's onCreate()
}

public void initLagu(Context theContext){
    mPlayer = Mediaplayer.create(theContext, R.raw.na);
}

public void playLagu(){

    mPlayer.start(); 
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. I had some doubts regarding to your Answer. Am i suppose to implement OnPreparedListener at initLagu()? and create() at playLagu()?

Comment: @Jack Powell - thanks for asking. Please take a look at my edited answer - I overlooked that Mediaplayer.create() is a static method. My bad :(